# Pygame - How to make pygame.mouse.get_pos in a rectangular area

Tags: python, pygame

Basically, the question is asking how to get the mouse location for a rectangular area.
So, instead of just finding if the mouse is on, for example, the coordinates 100, 100, it would find if the mouse is inside a rectangular area with the corners being at 100, 100, or where ever the rectangle is.

Sorry if this is a really simple question to answer, I just couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'find.' Do you mean find if the mouse is currently positioned inside a rectangular area?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init(); clock = pygame.time.Clock()
scr = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

image = pygame.image.load('image.png')
rect = image.get_rect()
rect.center = (320, 240)

while True:
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    scr.fill((0, 0, 0))
    scr.blit(image, rect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            print 'The mouse was click inside the image.'
```

Comment: The object contains a predefined method for such a test.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if we want an image on the rectangle? The answer is probably pretty obvious, so I'm sorry, but is there a way?

Comment: Yes instead of creating a brand new rectangle, use `image.get_rect()` to get the rectangle for a given image.

Comment: Sorry, but I another question. Where do I use this command in the code? When loading the image, drawing it, or something completely different? Sorry, but I'm kind of new to Pygame.

Comment: If you want to check continuously, then put it in your gameloop.

Comment: Here's a code snippet Joshkinz. Just be sure to rename the image.